# Limitation to MATLAB Hidden Line Removal?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've asked this question on Mathwork's site so if cross-posting isn't allowed let me know and I'll delete this.

I'm trying to render small objects and large objects together in MATLAB. I'm using the camera commands to restrict my field of view such that I can see both. However, when I do that, the hidden line removal fails on the small objects. I would have thought that hidden line removal would have been done at machine precision for floats, but it appears not. Is this a function of my graphics card or can I work around this?
The code below is the minimum example I could come up with. Plotted on an axis with default limits, the hidden line removal works fine (left) When the axis is set to large extents (compared to the object) the line removal fails (middle). When I make the axis disappear things are fine again (right). 
[image: three different rendered images as described in the problem]

For this example, I can just hide the axis and the output looks correct. But for what I'm actually trying to do, that's not an option. Any suggestions or can someone point me to the proper limit between the smallest and largest objects in a scene that will properly render?
The code to generate the spheres above is below. Thanks in advance!

Images as generated by MATLAB 2018A

```
clearvars
F1 = figure(1);
clf
set(F1,'color',[1 1 1],'Renderer','opengl'); % have to enable this to clip surfaces behind the camera


for step = [2 1 3] % out of order because the axis in case 2 is trying to hide the first plot

subplot(1,3,step)
view(gca,3);
camproj(gca,'Perspective'); % have to enable this to clip surfaces behind the camera

[Xs,Ys,Zs] = sphere(20);
r = 30e-6;
surf(gca,Xs*r,Ys*r,Zs*r);
axis(gca,'equal');

 % three different behaviors, pick a number 1, 2, or 3
switch step
    case 1 % this plots the sphere correctly
    %axis([-2 2 -2 2 -2 2]);
    %axis off

    case 2 % this messes up the hidden line removal
    axis([-2 2 -2 2 -2 2]);
    %axis off   

    case 3 % removing the axis walls fixes things again
    axis([-2 2 -2 2 -2 2]);
    axis off
end

% put viewpoint on unit sphere
camera_pos = get(gca,'CameraPosition');
mag_camera_pos = sqrt(sum(camera_pos.^2));
camera_pos = camera_pos / mag_camera_pos; 
set(gca,'CameraPosition',camera_pos);

final_angle = 2.5*atand(r/1);
set(gca,'CameraViewAngle',final_angle);
end

drawnow
```